# Quick use of MASShortcut framework on Swift project

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I am having trouble implementing [MASShortcut](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut) ([docs here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MASShortcut/)) in a Swift OSX project to listen for global hotkeys. I have managed to import the framework via CocoaPods, and I have a working MASShortcutView instance:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testShortcutView:MASShortcutView!
```

I also figured out how to monitor and trigger something with the shortcut (please tell me if this is correct):

```
let shortcut = MASShortcut(keyCode: keycode, modifierFlags: modifierkeys)

MASShortcutMonitor.sharedMonitor().registerShortcut(shortcut, withAction: callback)
```

---

> **The question here is, how can I get the keyCode and modifierFlags from my MASShortcutView?**

---

*I really thank you in advance, I searched everywhere and I can't find an example on how to do this on swift. All I can find is is objective-c, and I can't figure it out.*

Comment: at least how do I get the keycode and modifierFlags from that? Please anyone, it's the last detail to wrap up my app..

Comment: this blog post of mine may help: https://blog.rampatra.com/how-to-add-global-key-shortcuts-to-your-swift-app-using-masshortcut

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following code will register shortcut handler for Cmd+Shift+K key combination

```
let shortcut = MASShortcut.init(keyCode: UInt(kVK_ANSI_K), modifierFlags: UInt(NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask.rawValue + NSEventModifierFlags.ShiftKeyMask.rawValue))

MASShortcutMonitor.sharedMonitor().registerShortcut(shortcut, withAction: {
    print("Hello world")
})
```

Cmd and Shift - modifing keys. You should set them in the modifierFlags parameters. Full list of possible values is available in NSEventModifierFlags enum.

For your convenience I have placed sample project on github:

https://github.com/melifaro-/ShortCutSwiftSample

That handles shortcuts changes:

```
shortcutView.shortcutValueChange = { (sender) in

    let callback: (() -> Void)!

    if self.shortcutView.shortcutValue.keyCodeStringForKeyEquivalent == "k" {
        callback = {
            print("K shortcut handler")
        }
    } else {
        callback = {
            print("Default handler")
        }
    }

    MASShortcutMonitor.sharedMonitor().registerShortcut(self.shortcutView.shortcutValue, withAction: callback)
}
```

I have pushed changes into the repo. I would recommend to try following scenario:

Using the shortcut view:

1. Set Cmd+Shift+K shortcut
2. Set Cmd+Shift+J shortcut
3. Try this shortcuts - different callbacks should be performed

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately that was not the question, I know how to create hardcoded shortcuts. But I can't understand how to use the MASShortcutView to let users set their own shortcuts. Can you add that to your answer please?

Comment: @wavvves Ok, I'll do that

Comment: By the way, it's great that someone took the time to help me out. Swift is a nice try opening up app development to newcomers, but it still lacks support in translating all the objective-c examples out there.  Devs should be encouraged in updating their docs to include swift support. Thanks!

Comment: @wavvves Thanks for the feedback. I saw somewhere here one of framework creator (zoul). We can provide your feedback. Regarding whole situation I believe that major part of iOS/OS X software development will move from Obj-C to Swift in 1-2 years. Once that's happen all evolving frameworks will have first class support of Swift. So that's just matter of the time. Moreover I am eager to see what will happen once Swift 3 is released. Will it become really cross platform or not? I'm trilling with idea that one day I can develop apps for iOS/OS X, Android in particular and Linux in a whole in Swift

Comment: After trying this I have one more thing bugging me, how can I unregister previous shortcuts when I change them? When I set a new one, the previous one continues to work.

Comment: @wavvves That's easy - you basically need to store shortcut object when you are registering it. Once you realize that you don't need it anymore - use that previously stored obj for sending it to the shortcut monitor: `MASShortcutMonitor.sharedMonitor().unregisterShortcut(shortcut)`. I have updated the sample up. You can check it out.

Comment: Thanks ;), your sample project will certainly help others as it did help me

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5

```
let shortcut = MASShortcut(keyCode: kVK_ANSI_K, modifierFlags: [.command, .shift])

MASShortcutMonitor.shared()?.register(shortcut, withAction: {
    print("hello")
})
```